# Auto ajustar campos de manera automatica al poner la pantalla completa (Windows from)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Cuando pongo la pantalla completa no me gusta como quedan los campos quedan muy chicos y desordenados

> Que propiedad debo cambiar o que metodo debo usar?

Comment: No existe una propiedad nativa en winform que sea semejante al responsive de la web, acuerdate que existe desde antes que Internet sea masivo. Con WPF tiene algunas mejoras con respecto a eso y puede ser una opción, o sino programar con tecnologia hibrida como lo hace ElectronJS.

Comment: Tal como dijo @ronpy no existe algo así de forma nativa, incluso con WPF muchos controles mantienen su tamaño, en especial los textos. Lo que leí alguna vez es de crear una función que recorra todos los elementos de tu formulario y basado en el ancho del mismo redimensione esos elementos, nunca lo probé pero tiene lógica.

Comment: Lo unico que puedes hacer es mantener la forma de tu diseño dentro de un panel o algun otro objeto y usar la propiedad Anchor para que se mantengan juntos y no se pierda tu diseño cuando expandas a pantalla completa.